# Is there a difference in overhead between returning an object and returning the default value in a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, performance, scope, complexity-theory, chaining

Javascript functions can return objects or undefined.  I'm considering adopting a policy of always returning the object on which a function is called unless some other value is needed in order to facilitate method chaining.  Is there overhead associated with doing this by default even when there isn't a perceived need to chain at the time the function is written?

Comment: So your question is "Should I make every method possible chainable?"

Comment: Whenever you have such a question, just create a test case on http://jsperf.com/ and try it. Theory is useless here, the implementations of the JS engines are quite different!